# How to select data between populated date ranges sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have data in tables with start and end dates. How do I select data from a row by putting in a certain date?

For example: I want to enter a date and if it falls within the start and end date set then it should return the Data

My data is in the format

```
Data    StartDate    EndDate
a       01-01-1985   31-01-1985
b       01-02-1985   28-02-1985
c       01-03-1985   31-03-1985
```

I am thinking something like:

```
"SELECT Data FROM myTable WHERE ? BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate"
```

though I need a method so that I get the result 'b' if I enter the date '05-02-1985' for example.

Comment: How about: "SELECT Data FROM myTable WHERE ? > StartData and ? < EndDate;"?

Comment: hmm. i think that staement might be correct.. however i'm getting a problem with the andrpoid even seeing my table... might have to start another question for this...

Comment: @GregGiacovelli You would need to use `>=` and `<=`, and there is no difference between these operators and `BETWEEN`.

Comment: I mean I guess the question is a little vague then, like what is it that doesn't work. I understand how to use between but I thought the idea was not to be inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no built-in date type.
In order for comparisons to work correctly, you must use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), i.e., something like `yyyy-mm-dd`.
(Please note that the database storage format and the display format need not be identical.)